# Photoshop, трекинг

Tags: css

Подскажите, в вёрстке как правильно задавать трекинг из photoshop, показанный на рисунке?

т.е. как пересчитать значение `50` в css-свойство `letter-spacing`?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Формула для расчета `letter-spacing` в `em`:

```
X / 1000 = Y
```

Где `X` — значение интервала в Photoshop, а `Y`-то же значение, выраженное в `em` для CSS.

Соответственно:

```
50/1000 = letter-spacing: 0.05em
```

[источник](https://blog.sibirix.ru/2014/02/06/letter-spacing/)